# how to move slider using Rselenium?

Tags: rselenium

i am trying to move the slider to the max of 2000 px

```
driver = rsDriver(browser = c("firefox"))
remDr <- driver[["client"]]
remDr$navigate('https://www.qrcode-monkey.com/#url')

webElem <- remDr$findElement("xpath", "//span[@class='rz-pointer rz-pointer-min']")
```

i have tried these commands but it is not working

```
webElem$buttondown(2)
webElem$setElementAttribute("aria-valuetext", 2000)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simply click on pointer and press `end`

```
#launch browser
driver = rsDriver(browser = c("firefox"))
remDr <- driver[["client"]]
remDr$navigate('https://www.qrcode-monkey.com/#url')

#click element 
remDr$findElement(using = "xpath",'/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/span[5]')$clickElement()

#press end 
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath",'/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/span[5]')
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key="end"))
```

[image]